# Using inner frame to display a GUI within another GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, frame

I am currently working on a GUI .

I chose to base my GUI off of a bluej project - Scribble.

At the moment when you create a ScribbleGUI object the DrawDemo class creates a canvas that opens automatically simultaneously. I would prefer for the canvas window to not open unless it is to open up in a frame within the ScribbleGUI when ScribbleGUI is opened.

I tried to add an internal frame where the canvas would go with the code:

```
  //Create an internal frame to display the canvas within the ScribbleGUI.
  JInternalFrame internalCanvasFrame = new JInternalFrame("", true,
  true, true, true);
```

I did not know how to say that I wanted canvas to go there.

Do you feel I have chosen the appropriate method to have two GUIs going into each other? Or would it be better changing the code of the Canvas class to have the have all the same function the I have in ScribbleGUI class to operate?

Thank you

**ScribbleGUI class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
/**
 * Write a description of class ScribbleGUI here.
  * 
* @author (your name) 
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/
public class ScribbleGUI extends DrawDemo
{
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel panel;
private JButton buttonScribble;
private JButton buttonSquare;
private JButton buttonWheel;
private JLabel label;

public ScribbleGUI()
{
    GUI();                
}

public void GUI()
{

  //Set the frame size, visibility
  frame = new JFrame("Ugly Sketch");
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setSize(600,400);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  //Create an internal frame to display the canvas within the ScribbleGUI.
  JInternalFrame internalCanvasFrame = new JInternalFrame("", true,
  true, true, true);

  internalCanvasFrame.setSize(400, 300);
  internalCanvasFrame.setLocation(50, 50);
  internalCanvasFrame.setVisible(true);



  //Set the backround 
  panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
  panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

  //Create buttons
  buttonScribble = new JButton("Scribble!");
  buttonSquare = new JButton("Square!");
  buttonWheel = new JButton("Wheel!");
  label = new JLabel("Ugly Sketch");

  //Add actions to button
  buttonScribble.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eventScribble){
     colorScribble();
     } 

   });
   buttonSquare.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eventSquare){
     drawSquare();
     } 

   });
   buttonWheel.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eventWheel){
     drawWheel();
     } 

   });
  //Sreate space between button objects
  GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

  constraint.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
  constraint.gridx = 0;
  constraint.gridy = 1;
  panel.add(label,constraint);
  constraint.gridx = 0;
  constraint.gridy = 2;
  panel.add(buttonScribble,constraint);
  constraint.gridx = 0;
  constraint.gridy = 3; 
  panel.add(buttonSquare,constraint);
  constraint.gridx = 0;
  constraint.gridy = 4;
  panel.add(buttonWheel,constraint);




  //Set the panel to sit at the west of the frame
  frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.WEST);



}
```

}

---

**DrawDemo Class:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Class DrawDemo - provides some short demonstrations showing how to use            the 
 * Pen class to create various drawings.
 *
 * @author Michael Kölling and David J. Barnes
 * @version 2011.07.31
 */

public class DrawDemo 
{
private Canvas myCanvas;
private Random random;

/**
 * Prepare the drawing demo. Create a fresh canvas and make it visible.
 */
public DrawDemo()
{
    myCanvas = new Canvas("Drawing Demo", 500, 400);
    random = new Random();
}

/**
 * Draw a square on the screen.
 */
public void drawSquare()
{
    Pen pen = new Pen(320, 260, myCanvas);
    pen.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    square(pen);
}

/**
 * Draw a wheel made of many squares.
 */
public void drawWheel()
{
    Pen pen = new Pen(250, 200, myCanvas);
    pen.setColor(Color.RED);

    for (int i=0; i<36; i++) {
        square(pen);
        pen.turn(10);
    }
}

/**
 * Draw a square in the pen's color at the pen's location.
 */
private void square(Pen pen)
{
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        pen.move(100);
        pen.turn(90);
    }
}

/**
 * Draw some random squiggles on the screen, in random colors.
 */
public void colorScribble()
{
    Pen pen = new Pen(250, 200, myCanvas);

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        // pick a random color
        int red = random.nextInt(256);
        int green = random.nextInt(256);
        int blue = random.nextInt(256);
        pen.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));

        pen.randomSquiggle();
    }
}    

/**
 * Show canvas
 */
public Canvas showCanvas()
{
    myCanvas = new Canvas("Drawing Demo", 500, 400);
    return myCanvas;
}
/**
 * Clear the screen.
 */
public void clear()
{
    myCanvas.erase();
}
}
```

**Canvas class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

/**
 * Class Canvas - a class to allow for simple graphical 
 * drawing on a canvas.
 * 
 * @author Michael Kölling (mik)
 * @author Bruce Quig
     *
 * @version 2011.07.31
 */

public class Canvas
{
private JFrame frame;
private CanvasPane canvas;
private Graphics2D graphic;
private Color backgroundColor;
private Image canvasImage;

/**
 * Create a Canvas with default height, width and background color 
 * (300, 300, white).
 * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame     
 */
public Canvas(String title)
{
    this(title, 300, 300, Color.white);
}

/**
 * Create a Canvas with default background color (white).
 * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame
 * @param width  the desired width for the canvas
 * @param height  the desired height for the canvas
 */
public Canvas(String title, int width, int height)
{
    this(title, width, height, Color.white);
}

/**
 * Create a Canvas.
 * @param title  title to appear in Canvas Frame
 * @param width  the desired width for the canvas
 * @param height  the desired height for the canvas
 * @param bgClour  the desired background color of the canvas
 */
public Canvas(String title, int width, int height, Color bgColor)
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    canvas = new CanvasPane();
    frame.setContentPane(canvas);
    frame.setTitle(title);
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    backgroundColor = bgColor;
    frame.pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Set the canvas visibility and brings canvas to the front of screen
 * when made visible. This method can also be used to bring an already
 * visible canvas to the front of other windows.
 * @param visible  boolean value representing the desired visibility of
 * the canvas (true or false) 
 */
public void setVisible(boolean visible)
{
    if(graphic == null) {
        // first time: instantiate the offscreen image and fill it with
        // the background color
        Dimension size = canvas.getSize();
        canvasImage = canvas.createImage(size.width, size.height);
        graphic = (Graphics2D)canvasImage.getGraphics();
        graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
        graphic.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        graphic.setColor(Color.black);
    }
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Provide information on visibility of the Canvas.
 * @return  true if canvas is visible, false otherwise
 */
public boolean isVisible()
{
    return frame.isVisible();
}

/**
 * Draw the outline of a given shape onto the canvas.
 * @param  shape  the shape object to be drawn on the canvas
 */
public void draw(Shape shape)
{
    graphic.draw(shape);
    canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Fill the internal dimensions of a given shape with the current 
 * foreground color of the canvas.
 * @param  shape  the shape object to be filled 
 */
public void fill(Shape shape)
{
    graphic.fill(shape);
    canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Fill the internal dimensions of the given circle with the current 
 * foreground color of the canvas.
 * @param  xPos  The x-coordinate of the circle center point
 * @param  yPos  The y-coordinate of the circle center point
 * @param  diameter  The diameter of the circle to be drawn
 */
public void fillCircle(int xPos, int yPos, int diameter)
{
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos, yPos, diameter, diameter);
    fill(circle);
}

/**
 * Fill the internal dimensions of the given rectangle with the current 
 * foreground color of the canvas. This is a convenience method. A similar 
 * effect can be achieved with the "fill" method.
 */
public void fillRectangle(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height)
{
    fill(new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height));
}

/**
 * Erase the whole canvas.
 */
public void erase()
{
    Color original = graphic.getColor();
    graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
    Dimension size = canvas.getSize();
    graphic.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    graphic.setColor(original);
    canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Erase the internal dimensions of the given circle. This is a 
 * convenience method. A similar effect can be achieved with
 * the "erase" method.
 */
public void eraseCircle(int xPos, int yPos, int diameter)
{
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(xPos, yPos, diameter,      diameter);
    erase(circle);
}

/**
 * Erase the internal dimensions of the given rectangle. This is a 
 * convenience method. A similar effect can be achieved with
 * the "erase" method.
 */
public void eraseRectangle(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height)
{
    erase(new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, width, height));
}

/**
 * Erase a given shape's interior on the screen.
 * @param  shape  the shape object to be erased 
 */
public void erase(Shape shape)
{
    Color original = graphic.getColor();
    graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
    graphic.fill(shape);              // erase by filling background color
    graphic.setColor(original);
    canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Erases a given shape's outline on the screen.
 * @param  shape  the shape object to be erased 
 */
public void eraseOutline(Shape shape)
{
    Color original = graphic.getColor();
    graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
    graphic.draw(shape);  // erase by drawing background color
    graphic.setColor(original);
    canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Draws an image onto the canvas.
 * @param  image   the Image object to be displayed 
 * @param  x       x co-ordinate for Image placement 
 * @param  y       y co-ordinate for Image placement 
 * @return  returns boolean value representing whether the image was 
 *          completely loaded 
 */
public boolean drawImage(Image image, int x, int y)
{
    boolean result = graphic.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    canvas.repaint();
    return result;
}

/**
 * Draws a String on the Canvas.
 * @param  text   the String to be displayed 
 * @param  x      x co-ordinate for text placement 
 * @param  y      y co-ordinate for text placement
 */
public void drawString(String text, int x, int y)
{
    graphic.drawString(text, x, y);   
    canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Erases a String on the Canvas.
 * @param  text     the String to be displayed 
 * @param  x        x co-ordinate for text placement 
 * @param  y        y co-ordinate for text placement
 */
public void eraseString(String text, int x, int y)
{
    Color original = graphic.getColor();
    graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
    graphic.drawString(text, x, y);   
    graphic.setColor(original);
    canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Draws a line on the Canvas.
 * @param  x1   x co-ordinate of start of line 
 * @param  y1   y co-ordinate of start of line 
 * @param  x2   x co-ordinate of end of line 
 * @param  y2   y co-ordinate of end of line 
 */
public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    graphic.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);   
    canvas.repaint();
}

/**
 * Sets the foreground color of the Canvas.
 * @param  newColor   the new color for the foreground of the Canvas 
 */
public void setForegroundColor(Color newColor)
{
    graphic.setColor(newColor);
}

/**
 * Returns the current color of the foreground.
 * @return   the color of the foreground of the Canvas 
 */
public Color getForegroundColor()
{
    return graphic.getColor();
}

/**
 * Sets the background color of the Canvas.
 * @param  newColor   the new color for the background of the Canvas 
 */
public void setBackgroundColor(Color newColor)
{
    backgroundColor = newColor;   
    graphic.setBackground(newColor);
}

/**
 * Returns the current color of the background
 * @return   the color of the background of the Canvas 
 */
public Color getBackgroundColor()
{
    return backgroundColor;
}

/**
 * changes the current Font used on the Canvas
 * @param  newFont   new font to be used for String output
 */
public void setFont(Font newFont)
{
    graphic.setFont(newFont);
}

/**
 * Returns the current font of the canvas.
 * @return     the font currently in use
 **/
public Font getFont()
{
    return graphic.getFont();
}

/**
 * Sets the size of the canvas.
 * @param  width    new width 
 * @param  height   new height 
 */
public void setSize(int width, int height)
{
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    Image oldImage = canvasImage;
    canvasImage = canvas.createImage(width, height);
    graphic = (Graphics2D)canvasImage.getGraphics();
    graphic.setColor(backgroundColor);
    graphic.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    graphic.drawImage(oldImage, 0, 0, null);
    frame.pack();
}

/**
 * Returns the size of the canvas.
 * @return     The current dimension of the canvas
 */
public Dimension getSize()
{
    return canvas.getSize();
}

/**
 * Waits for a specified number of milliseconds before finishing.
 * This provides an easy way to specify a small delay which can be
 * used when producing animations.
 * @param  milliseconds  the number 
 */
public void wait(int milliseconds)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(milliseconds);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // ignoring exception at the moment
    }
}

/************************************************************************
 * Inner class CanvasPane - the actual canvas component contained in the
 * Canvas frame. This is essentially a JPanel with added capability to
 * refresh the image drawn on it.
 */
private class CanvasPane extends JPanel
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(canvasImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java GUI you need Container to which you can any Component. Since Frame itself is Container and Component (see [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html)) you can add it to another container and so to another Frame or Panel or any other containers.

The only confusion could be if you add the same Component twice. It doesn't matter to the same container or different. The same object means one object in 2 containers - because both containers will try to operate/modify/notify the same object with different events and it makes it unstable.

As long as every Component is unique you can combine them in any Container in any order. Again, Container is Component too, so make it uniques too.